# Group permissions ineffective, permission still denied

Tags: permissions, files, group

I've got a problem with UNIX permissions : I'm working under Debian Squeeze, and one of my scripts, run by `www-data`, needs to move a file, `23550.zip`, placed in the home directory of another user, `autodo`, to a subdirectory in this user's home (`/home/autodo/.processed`) to mark it as already processed.

I tried to change the group ownership of `/home/autodo`, `/home/autodo/23550.zip` and `/home/autodo/.processed` to the group `www-data` to allow the `www-data` user to move this file, but it still fails saying `Permission denied`, as you can see below (as I'm French, I translated french messages back to English, although I can't be sure the translation is the one displayed in English version of these commands) :

```
sh-4.1$ ls -lah /home/autodo
total 27M
drwxr-xr-x  3 autodo www-data 4,0K  9 janv. 15:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 88 root   root     4,0K  8 janv. 15:21 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers 4,8K  5 sept. 23:14 19236.zip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo www-data  26M  9 janv. 14:26 23550.zip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers 2,3K  6 janv. 20:44 3194.zip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers 1,1M  5 sept. 23:38 53274.zip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers  585  6 sept. 00:50 70069.zip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers  220 16 nov.  15:10 .bash_logout
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers 3,2K 16 nov.  15:10 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 autodo www-data 4,0K  9 janv. 15:16 .processed
-rwxr-xr-x  1 autodo ftpusers  675 16 nov.  15:10 .profile
sh-4.1$ ls -lah /home/autodo/.processed
total 66M
drwxr-xr-x 2 autodo www-data 4,0K  9 janv. 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 autodo www-data 4,0K  9 janv. 15:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 3,8K  8 janv. 22:42 100583.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 1,7K  9 janv. 02:48 12211.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 2,2K  8 janv. 22:43 166273.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 424K  8 janv. 22:52 193894.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 1,2M  9 janv. 01:13 20662.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers  59M  9 janv. 00:43 22352.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 1,2M  8 janv. 22:42 23704.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 214K  9 janv. 02:34 24704.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers  632  9 janv. 01:17 26360.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 2,8K  9 janv. 01:03 31795.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 106K  9 janv. 00:11 31797.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 413K  9 janv. 00:44 31799.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 4,4K  8 janv. 22:30 31803.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 2,3K  5 janv. 21:19 3194.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers  13K  8 janv. 23:33 5705.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 2,8K  8 janv. 22:19 5858.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers  86K  9 janv. 04:34 604.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 2,6M  9 janv. 03:34 7091.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 3,4K  8 janv. 21:25 7878.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 752K  9 janv. 03:37 8127.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 6,1K  8 janv. 22:01 84846.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 autodo ftpusers 358K  9 janv. 02:42 989.zip
sh-4.1$ id
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),2000(ftpusers)
sh-4.1$ mv /home/autodo/23550.zip /home/autodo/.processed/
mv: unable to move « /home/autodo/23550.zip » to « /home/autodo/.processed/23550.zip »: Permission denied
```

I also tried to `setgid` this user's directory, but it also failed with the same `Permission denied`, and to `adduser www-data ftpusers`, but it still failed with the same error.

I have to admit that I'm lost; I always thought that the permissions of a group owning a file meant the same than the owner ones, but this problem contradicts this, and I can't think that there can be such a bug in the Linux kernel, so I *have to had missed something*, but where, dammit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since a `mv` is modifying both the "to directory" and the "from directory" you need write permissions on the files you are moving as well as the directories you are moving to/from.

```
chmod -R g+w /home/autodo/
```

this will recursively add write permissions for group for everything under /home/autodo

Comment: Naaah... I'm so stupid. How could I let pass such an evident error? As we say here, _Oh, le con!_.

Comment: @Penegal glad to help.